# MYSQL : select count with union three table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I have three table content information about posts

and each table  has Post_id it's foreign_key for Post table

```
first table = `likes`  
second table = `Comment`  
and last one = `Visitor`
```

each Table  has some info about users like session or id and etc

i need to create new view table contain post id and the number of visitor , likes , comment

i tried this

```
SELECT *


  from (

 select id   , count(id) as Comment  
from Post left join Comment  on  id = Post_id 
group by id

  UNION

select id, count(id) as Visitor    
from Post left join Visitor  on id = Post_id 
group by id
UNION

select id, count(id) as Likes  
from Post left join Likes  on id = Post_id 
group by id

) CountsTable
GROUP BY CountsTable.id
```

but it didnt work .
i dont know why the result is only the first inner select

in my example the result is

```
|    id  | Comment| 
|--------|------- | 
|    1   |   55   |    
|    2   |   25   |   
|    3   |   12   |
```

i expect something like that

```
| id | Comment | Likes | Visitor |
|--------------|-------|---------|
|  1 |   55    |  100  |   2000  |
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `UNION`. Count the records for each post in all three tables and Left Join result with `Post` table

Try something like this

```
SELECT id,
        comments,
        vistors,
        likes
FROM   Post p
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(Post_id) comments, Post_id
                    FROM   Comment
                    GROUP  BY Post_id) c
                ON p.id = c.Post_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(Post_id) vistors, Post_id
                    FROM   Visitor
                    GROUP  BY Post_id) v
                ON p.id = v.Post_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(Post_id) likes, Post_id
                    FROM   Likes
                    GROUP  BY Post_id) l
                ON p.id = l.Post_id
```

Comment: worked for me thank you but when i tried to make view from this i got 
"View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `Left Join` query, e.g.:

```
select u.id, count(distinct l.id) as likes, count(distinct c.id) as comments
from user u left join likes l on u.id = l.user_id
left join comments c on u.id = c.user_id
group by u.id;
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25a7af/8/0)**.

Comment: it didnt work 
 #1054 - Unknown column 'l.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Check the column name in likes table. Also, check my create table script on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, SUM(Comment),SUM(Visitor),SUM(Likes) from (

select id   , count(id) as Comment, 0 as Visitor, 0 as Likes  
from Post left join Comment  on  id = Post_id 
group by id

UNION ALL

select id, 0 as Comment, count(id) as Visitor , 0 as Likes    
from Post left join Visitor  on id = Post_id 
group by id

UNION ALL

select id, 0 as Comment, 0 as Visitor, count(id) as Likes  
from Post left join Likes  on id = Post_id 
group by id

) CountsTable
GROUP BY CountsTable.id
```